# parse json with aeson when first key is variable

Tags: haskell

My json looks like this

```
{
    "NW011": {
        "version": 1.0,
        "compatiblehardware": ["N21"],
        "description": "TWIN"
   }
}
```

The problem is that the key NW011 is variable. I know this key when I start parsing but I have no idea how to declare the data type and instance for aeson.

Comment: The version appears to be a number. But versions in general are strings, not numbers. What are you going to do about something at version 1.2.3A?

Comment: If you know the key before you start parsing, you could define a function that takes the key in as a parameter and returns the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your JSON as a (Map Text Thing) where Thing is your record type.  Tested code follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Aeson 
import Data.Map (Map)
import GHC.Generics

-- Record representing a single thing
data Thing =
    Thing { 
        version             :: Float,
        compatiblehardware  :: [Text],
        description         :: Text
    } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Thing

main :: IO()
main = do
    inh <- BSL.readFile "json.txt" 
    case decode inh :: Maybe (Map Text Thing) of
        Just parsed -> print parsed
        Nothing -> print "Unparsable"
```

Here's the test data, "json.txt":

```
{
   "NW011": {
        "version": 1.0,
        "compatiblehardware": ["N21"],
        "description": "TWIN"
   },
   "NW012": {
        "version": 2.4,
        "compatiblehardware": ["N21", "N22"],
        "description": "TURBO"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to declare a data type that models what your data actually is. I presume that the "NW011" is effectively acting as a kind of field, albeit one that the JSON format in question has promoted to look like a record name. So:

```
data Thing = Thing {
   thingName :: Text,  -- E.g. "NW011"
   thingVersion :: Text, -- I'm assuming that "Version" could include "1.2.3A" and hence should be a string, not a number.
   thingCompatible :: [Text],
   thingDescription :: Text
}
```

Now the instance. Normally when you parse JSON you would have an object with fixed field names, so you can use ".:" to extract them. In this case your outermost structure is a one-field object, where the field is called "NW011" and contains a more traditional object.

So you need to write an instance that retrieves this raw object. I'll assume that you could have several such objects with different names like "NW012" etc, so actually your outer structure is a list of these things. If you parse the example you gave then you will get a one-element list.

In Aeson an "Object" is a wrapper around a look-up table (i.e. a HashMap). So all you need to do is iterate through the HashMap extracting the objects by name. So the answer should look something like this (although I haven't tried compiling it):

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H

instance FromJSON [Thing] where
   parseJSON (Object v) = mapM parseItem $ H.toList v
      -- 'v' is a HashMap containing a key "NW011".
   where
      parseItem (k, Object v2) = 
         -- "v2" is a HashMap containing keys for the fixed field names ("version" etc.)
         Thing k <$> 
         v2 .: "version" <*>
         v2 .: "compatiblehardware" <*>
         v2 .: "description"
```

Note that this just gives the success cases. Your code should also include cases where the arguments to parseJSON and parseItem are not objects.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this reply. I am new to haskell and have been fighting neary this exact problem for a couple days (Except I am using YAML). I seem to be running into a problem with the types of v and v2. Any chance you could offer some pointers? Code and errors over at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffutter/4133c49d8dd52ce36d8efb0b6be8ac4f). Thanks

Comment: There are a number of things going on here. First, my mistake, I forgot that H.mapWithKey returns a new hashmap, not a list, and also that Aeson uses strict hashmaps. See the updated text above, including the change to parseItem. Apart from that, the code in your Gist seems to be parsing groups that have a "name" field in the object rather than the variable key you described, so this isn't solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Its starting to make sense now and nearly works. I've updated the gist and added sample YAML. I'm getting some error about something expecting a group but is getting a list instead.

Comment: You need to make it "instance FromJSON [Group] where". You will need to enable FlexibleInstances for this.

Comment: `v .: "version" <*>`, `v .: "compatiblehardware"` and `v .: "description"` should be `v2 .: "version" <*>`, `v2 .: "compatiblehardware"` and `v2 .: "description"`. Also, why doesn't StackOverflow let me edit this post? so moronic

Answer (score 3):

JSON objects in Aeson are just hash maps.  You can extract all the keys if you desire.  In this case you can't have a datatype with a field named after your JSON key because that isn't consistent, but you can still parse and use the JSON just fine.  Untested code follows.

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.HashMap.Strict as HMap

parseMyJSON :: Value -> Parser (Text,Value)
parseMyJSON (Object v) =
     case HMap.toList v of
        [(k,v)] -> (k, v)
        _       -> fail "More than one key - who sent this thing?"
parseMyJSON _ = fail "Incorrect JSON - expected an object."
```